# Partially connected neural network for multi-level classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I want to create a partially connected neural network. A simplified version is shown below.
[image: partially connected network]

I simplified the network to make it easier to understand. The original one is more complicated. Here, after the input layer, I have a category level layer. The sample ground truth values are shown there as well, i.e., `[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. The last layer is the subcategory layer which always includes one 1, and the rest as zero, i.e., `[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. The category and subcategory are partially linked but the input layer is fully linked to the category layer.

This is the code that I wrote for it.

```
input_      = Input(shape=5)

cat_layer   = Dense(4*3, activation='sigmoid', name='cat')(input_)

list_of_subcat_layers = []
for idx, i in enumerate([2,4,3]):
    final_subcat  = Dense(i, activation = 'softmax')(cat_layer[:,idx*4:(idx+1)*4])
    list_of_subcat_layers.append(final_subcat)

subcat_output = concatenate(list_of_subcat_layers, name='subcat')

model         = Model(input_, [cat_layer, subcat_output])
model_cat     = Model(input_, cat_layer)
model_subcat  = Model(input_, subcat_output)

loss          = {'cat':'categorical_crossentropy','subcat':'categorical_crossentropy'}
loss_weights  = {'cat':1.,'subcat':1.}
metrics       = {'cat': 'acc','subcat': 'acc'}
optimizer     = Adam(learning_rate=3e-05, epsilon=1e-08)
model.compile(loss=loss, loss_weights=loss_weights, metrics=metrics, optimizer=optimizer)
```

However, I have a problem with the code. "softmax" activation should be done once for all subcategory levels, but I think in my code, it is done once per subcategory. How can have it once for all?

Please also comment on whether the other parts of the model (code) make sense.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure if I understand the model correctly but it seems like you probably need to concatenate all of the subcategory outputs before performing the softmax activation on them?

Comment: How do you mean? Can you post your suggestion?

Comment: Actually, I take that back. I think once per subcategory is fine, because only one category is activated, right? So multiply the post-softmax subcategory outputs by the catagory outputs (all are 0 except for 1 category) so that all irrelevant sub-category outputs are zeroed. Let me know if this makes sense